# Python Flask Error "missing required positional arguments" (even though they were supplied)

Tags: python, flask

I have an flask index route that is redirecting to another route like this:

```python
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        filepath="some/path/"
        top_1 = "something"
        top_2 = "somethingelse"
        top_3 = "somethingelse"
        return redirect(url_for('display_preds', filepath=filepath, 
                                      top_1=top_1, top_2=top_2, top_3=top_3), 
                                      code=307)
```

And "display_preds" looks like this:

```python
@app.route('/display_preds', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def display_preds(filepath, top_1, top_2, top_3):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render_template("prediction.html")
```

finally in the "prediction.html" page I have this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is just a test</h1>
    <img src="{{ filepath }}" alt="some text">
    <br>
    <p> {{ top_1 }} </p> <br>
    <p> {{ top_2 }} </p> <br>
    <p> {{ top_3 }} </p>
</body>
</html>
```

After executing this I can see that the redirect() has values for "filepath", "top_1" etc. because I see it trying to POST something like this:

`address/display_preds?filepath=%2some%2file%2path&top_2=something&top_1=somethingelse&top_3=somethingelse`

Why am I getting an error that says:

`TypeError: display_preds() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'filepath', 'top_1', 'top_2', and 'top_3'`

UPDATE:

I tried changing the route to `@app.route('/display_preds/<filepath>/<top_1>/<top_2>/<top_3>/', methods=['GET','POST'])` but that just changes the error to this:

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'display_preds/filepath/top_1/top_2/top_3' with values ['filepath', 'top_1', 'top_2', 'top_3']. Did you mean 'display_preds' instead?
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you providing the values for `render_template`?

You can either use a context dict like

`context = {"filepath": filepath, "top_1": top_1, "top_2":top_2, "top_3": top_3}` 
`render_template("prediction.html", context=context)`

or directly in `render_template` with:

`render_template("prediction.html", filepath=filepath, top_1=top_1, top_2=top_2, top_3=top3)`

UPDATE: Your redirect is using a GET request to the new url, but in your endpoint, you are not retrieving the parameters with `request.args.get("top_1")`.

```
def display_preds():
  filepath = request.args.get("filepath")
  top_1 = request.args.get("top_1")
  ....
```

Comment: Thanks Kenjin for the advice! I implemented this change but I still get the exact same error I originally had :/

Comment: @DavidSkarbrevik The problem in the code is, that your `redirect` is using a GET to the new page. But in the new page, you are not retrieving the data from the `request` with `request.args.get("top_1")`

Comment: I tried using the request.args.get() but still getting the same error. I think it's actually a POST not GET because of the "code=307" parameter in my redirect() call.